# Use query with InnerJoin

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I'm trying to pass this query to inner join, but it does not know how?

This is the query I want to use InnerJoin with these values ​​where

```
SELECT 
  ticket.id_ticket, 
  ticket.id_rede, 
  historico.id_historico, 
  historico.id_ticket, 
  centro.id_centro, 
  eqpto.id_eqpto, 
  eqpto.nome, 
  centro.sigla_centro, 
  interface.id_interface, 
  interface.id_eqpto, 
  interface.desig, 
  tecnologia.descricao, 
  interface.id_tecnologia, 
  tecnologia.id_tecnologia, 
  eqpto.id_centro, 
  eqpto.id_rede
FROM 
  app_gpa_ticket.ticket, 
  app_gpa_ticket.historico, 
  dados_v3.centro, 
  dados_v3.eqpto, 
  dados_v3.interface, 
  dados_v3.tecnologia
WHERE 
  ticket.id_ticket = historico.id_ticket AND
  centro.id_centro = eqpto.id_centro AND
  eqpto.id_eqpto = interface.id_eqpto AND
  eqpto.id_rede = ticket.id_rede AND
  tecnologia.id_tecnologia = interface.id_tecnologia;
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does “pass this query to inner join” mean, and what “does not know how”?

Comment: Try to be more clear on your question. Can you show us the error message you get when you execute that query?

Comment: Not sure how do you expect people to understand when you yourself don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just guessing, but user is looking to go from old where joins to ansi-92 inner join syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to go to the standard (explicit) syntax. What you need to do is take what would be your `JOIN` operators in the `WHERE` clause and move them near the table itself. What you need to know is what tables on the left (Before the `INNER JOIN` operator you are joining to the right (After the `INNER JOIN` operator)

```
SELECT 
ticket.id_ticket, 
ticket.id_rede, 
historico.id_historico, 
historico.id_ticket, 
centro.id_centro, 
eqpto.id_eqpto, 
eqpto.nome, 
centro.sigla_centro, 
interface.id_interface, 
interface.id_eqpto, 
interface.desig, 
tecnologia.descricao, 
interface.id_tecnologia, 
tecnologia.id_tecnologia, 
eqpto.id_centro, 
eqpto.id_rede
FROM app_gpa_ticket.ticket 
INNER JOIN app_gpa_ticket.historico ON ticket.id_ticket = historico.id_ticket
INNER JOIN dados_v3.eqpto ON eqpto.id_rede = ticket.id_rede
INNER JOIN dados_v3.interface ON eqpto.id_eqpto = interface.id_eqpto
INNER JOIN dados_v3.centro ON centro.id_centro = eqpto.id_centro
INNER JOIN  dados_v3.tecnologia ON tecnologia.id_tecnologia = interface.id_tecnologia
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I wanted to do Elias.


Thank you very much!